# Can you run a specific Xcuitest from the command line?

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, xcode-ui-testing

Playing with iOS 9.0, Xcode GM and the new Xcuitesting framework. How can I run a specific test from the command line instead of having to click play in the ide? I know there's a shortcut to run all the tests but I want to run a single test.

Thanks!

Comment: something new about this issue? I've the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34793731/xcode-ui-test-can-i-specify-a-particular-test-that-i-want-to-run-from-terminal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do that with [xctool](https://github.com/facebook/xctool) command line tool for running specific test class,

```
xctool -workspace YourWorkspace.xcworkspace -scheme YourScheme test -only myUITestTarget:UITestClass
```

You can also use `xcodebuild` to run the entire test suite as explained here,
https://krausefx.com/blog/run-xcode-7-ui-tests-from-the-command-line

Comment: is this tool appropriate for the XCode-UI-Test? I tried it but i have this error: [Info] Loading settings for scheme '....' ...ERROR: build-tests: 'XTests' is not a testing target in this scheme.

Comment: `xctool` doesn't support UI tests according to this issue: https://github.com/facebook/xctool/issues/534 .