# Xcode-Ui-Test: Can i specify a particular test that i want to run from terminal

Tags: ios, shell, xcodebuild, xcode-ui-testing

i wrote a ui test in new xcode 7 with swift 2.0. I have a script, that i run from terminal to execute the ui-tests. Here is the command line:

```
xcodebuild -workspace App.xcworkspace -scheme "App-Scheme" -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=9.1' test
```

The problem is, this command line run all the test-cases into my test. How is it possible the specify a particular test?

Any ideas?
Cheers.

Comment: Hey,

new update from here http://shashikantjagtap.net/wwdc-2016-continuous-integration-with-xcode-server-and-xctest-updates/

it is possible with Xcode 8. Just install xcode 8 and in terminal xcodebuild --version. Check the two last one parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I post this impovement to Apple. As i know, Now the only way - to substitute the *.xcscheme file with added "< SkippedTests >" info.